# How to make a C# class that is capable of data binding in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am very new to programming in xaml and C#, but I am trying to learn the basics of how to make a C# class that is capable of data binding (one-way data binding at the moment). From what I read, the class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. The app that I made is very basic. When the "set phone number" button is pressed, a set property is called on the customer class to update its phone number attribute.  From what I understand, this should trigger NotifyPropertyChanged() and cause the new number to be displayed in the text attribute of the xaml label class.  I have spent hours researching trying to figure this out, so any help/advice on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataBinding.Models
{
    public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        private string customerNameValue = String.Empty;
        public string phoneNumberValue = String.Empty;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public Customer()
        {
            phoneNumberValue = "(312)555-0100";
        }


        public string PhoneNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return this.phoneNumberValue;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != this.phoneNumberValue)
                {
                    this.phoneNumberValue = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code behind for the xaml where I instantiate customer and set the binding context.  The app works when I use non data binding code to set the new phone number, as you can see in the commented out code below, but does not work otherwise.

```
using DataBinding.Models;
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DataBinding
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            stacks.BindingContext = customer;

        }

        private void Set_Number(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            customer.PhoneNumber = "1800-395-5482";
            //title.Text = customer.PhoneNumber; //The app works when I set the text attriute using non data binding code.
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBinding"
             x:Class="DataBinding.MainPage">

    <StackLayout x:Name="stacks" Padding="20">
        <Label x:Name="title"
               Text="{Binding phoneNumberValue}"        
               VerticalOptions="Center" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Button Text="Set phone number" Clicked="Set_Number"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Please change your word 'Xamal' to [XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295302.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binding is using "phoneNumberValue"

```
Text="{Binding phoneNumberValue}"
```

but you are setting the property "PhoneNumber"

```
customer.PhoneNumber = "1800-395-5482";
```

You need to bind to the public property "PhoneNumber".  Typically the backing field for the property is private, not public.

Comment: That you for the help! I didn't realize that you could not bind to a field. It is now working.